# MySQLi join and display details differently from 2 tables

Tags: php, mysql

Hello I have actually asked a similar question a while ago but only just realized I did not get an answer that solves my problem.

I have 2 tables in a MySQL DB, that are connected by the same main id, the following code is just a simplified example of the original code:

table1:

```
+-----------------------+
| main_id | name | type |
+-----------------------+
```

table2:

```
+----------------------------------------+
| main_id | secondary_id | color | price |
+----------------------------------------+
```

the result I want to achieve is to get every row of table 1, and under each one list all the linked by main id rows from table2, for example:

table1 rows:

```
+-------------------+
| 1 | name1 | type1 |
| 2 | name2 | type2 |
| 3 | name3 | type3 |
+-------------------+
```

table2 rows:

```
+----+------+----------+------+
| 1  |  23  |   red    |  500 |
| 1  |  24  |  blue    |  600 |
| 1  |  25  |  green   |  700 |
| 2  |  26  |  pink    |  400 |
| 2  |  27  |  purple  |  200 |
| 3  |  28  |  white   |  100 |
+----+------+----------+------+
```

result in display:

```
<h1 class="1">name1, type1</h1>
<div class="23">red,500</div>
<div class="23">red,500</div>
<div class="24">green,700</div>

<h1 class="2">name2, type2</h1>
<div class="25">pink,400</div>
<div class="26">purple,200</div>
```

And so on...I was using a while loop inside a while loop which wasn't giving me the required result, then I was advised to use MySQL JOIN, but when I do I get all values of the matching ids and cant display the headings only once and then list the related results under it, can someone please help me?

this is a simplified query i was using:

```
while($rows = $headings->fetch_array(MYSQLI_BOTH)) 
{
    $id = $rows['id'];
    $conts_q = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM `table2` WHERE id='$id'");
    $conts_numr = $conts_q->num_rows;

    if($conts_numr==0)
    {
        //Display empty
    }
    else
    {
        while($row2 = $conts_q->fetch_array(MYSQLI_BOTH))
        {
            //Get details and display
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your description, you use main_id, but in the code you use just id. Not sure which you're really using here - you will have to edit the code below to match your actual column names. If the database column name is actually main_id, then for instance the line with $id = $rows['id'] would have to be $rows['main_id']. Or it won't work.

```
while($rows = $headings->fetch_array(MYSQLI_BOTH)) 
{
    echo '<h1 class="'.$rows['id'].'">'.$rows['name1'].', '.$rows['type'].'</h1>';

    $id = $rows['id'];
    $conts_q = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM `table2` WHERE id='$id'");
    $conts_numr = $conts_q->num_rows;

    if($conts_numr==0)
    {
        //Display empty
    }
    else
    {
        while($row2 = $conts_q->fetch_array(MYSQLI_BOTH))
        {
            if ($row2['id'] == $id) {
                echo '<div class="'.$row2['secondary_id'].'">'.$row2['color'].', '.$row2['price'].'</div>';
            }
        }//while
    }//else
}//while
```

Comment: like I wrote, this is just a simplified example of the original code.

Comment: Can you please explain why are you equaling the row['id'] to $id again after the query should have already taken care of that because that is the problem I had, it didn't select the only the ids I wanted but rather all of them?

Comment: That first line - while($rows = $headings....) - isn't that pulling from a previous query on Table 1?  It's not written in your code, but I assumed that there must be a query above that line in your code somewhere, and it must be pulling from table1. Something like "SELECT * FROM table1"?  Is that not true?

Comment: Yes this is true, I meant the second query though, in which I select * WHERE id='$id', and then you added another if statement equaling to the id...still this solution doesn't work for me, if there are no results it shows properly but if there are, it shows all rows for each id instead of showing only unique rows per id...I don't understand whyyy :(

Comment: So what are your actual database column names? Is the column named "id" or is it "main_id"?

Comment: In table 1 its named id in table2 its named secondary_id, and my second query is WHERE secondary_id='$id'

Comment: Right now, this query actually works but for some reason it shows only the last value for each id rather then  showing all values with same id